# how to make uwp flyout full screen

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am creating an app for a tablet, which will display a grid full of data. I want to be able to click on each item and then have that data displayed in a flyout or popup or some other dialog so I can edit it like a form. So far, I am using a flyout which contains a stackpanel like so:

```
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="10 0 10 0">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Activities}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemsPanelTemplate}">
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:TimActivity">
                <Grid Tapped="GridView_Tapped">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource TimActivityTypeToStringConverter}}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind StartTime}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind EndTime}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{x:Bind From}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{x:Bind To}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{x:Bind Comment}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{x:Bind Path=Chargeable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}" />
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <Flyout Placement="Full">
                            <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Activity"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource TimActivityTypeToStringConverter}}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Start Time"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind StartTime}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="End Time"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind EndTime}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="From"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind From}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="To"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind To}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Comment"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind Comment}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="Chargeable?"/>
                                        <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind Path=Chargeable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToStringConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Flyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

I am setting the `Placement` to `Full`, but it only stretches the flyout vertically as opposed to being full screen. Can you please advise if a. flyout is the right control for this, and b. how to make it fullscreen?

Comment: `StackPanel` will never allow more space than it needs. Try a `Grid` with `RowDefinitions`, which will allow the `Children` to be spaced properly.

Comment: The purpose of a Flyout is exactly to use only the space it needs for its children controls!   If you want to create an “edit page” for your items, then just implement a navigation system in your app... or just a Master-detail page.

Comment: thanks @LucaLindholm. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, we recommend you use [`ConnectedAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/connected-animation) to approach. For more steps please refer this code [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/ConnectedAnimationPages/CardPage.xaml.cs#L10).

```
private void TipsGrid_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectedAnimation animation = null;

    // Get the collection item corresponding to the clicked item.
    var container = collection.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
    if (container != null)
    {
        // Stash the clicked item for use later. We'll need it when we connect back from the detailpage.
        _storedItem = Convert.ToInt32(container.Content);

        // Prepare the connected animation.
        // Notice that the stored item is passed in, as well as the name of the connected element. 
        // The animation will actually start on the Detailed info page.
        animation = collection.PrepareConnectedAnimation("forwardAnimation", _storedItem, "connectedElement");

    }

    SmokeGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   // SmokeGrid.DataContext = e.ClickedItem;
    animation.TryStart(destinationElement);
}
```

**Update**

> Then I should be able to edit all the fields in that form, and when saved, it reflects in the grid.

You could make model that inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then use two-way binding to bind the model property with xaml code.

```
<GridView Name="collection" ItemClick="Conllection_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="connectedElement"  Height="100" Width="100" Background="Orange">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Content,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           TextAlignment="Center"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

You could pass the item to the popup grid when the `GridView` ItemClick.

```
private void Conllection_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectedAnimation animation = null;
    var container = collection.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
    if(container != null)
    {
        _storedItem = container.Content;
        animation = collection.PrepareConnectedAnimation("forwardAnimation", _storedItem, "connectedElement");
    }
    SmokeGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   // pass the item DataContext.
    SmokeGrid.DataContext = e.ClickedItem;

    animation.TryStart(destinationElement);
}
```

The  mini [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/WorkingWithConnectAnimation) has updated and you could refer.

Comment: thanks for the response @Nico Zhu, but I am less concerned about animation, and more want to just be able to edit a grid item in a separate popup form that stacks on top as an item is clicked. Then I should be able to edit all the fields in that form, and when saved, it reflects in the grid.

Comment: thanks very much Nico. I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Flyout Placement="Full">
```

This is the best way to go, even if it wont stretch Horizontally
You can also enable **LightDismissOverlayMode**, to get a more 'modal' options experience.

Full screen flyout would make no sense, you wouldn't even be able to dismiss it without adding further exit buttons.

But if you really wanna do it, you can use **Popup**, it is a more primitive product of **FlyoutBase** and then you can just bind to it the actual Width And Height of containing page like :

```
<Popup   Height="{Binding yourpage.ActualHeight}"  Width="{Binding yourpage.ActualWidth}" />
<Button Background="Orange" Height="50" Width=50 />
```

Popup is display controled by its **IsOpen** property, so adapt accordingly.

Architectural wise, it is more appropriate if you use a single flyout that is dynamically associated to whatever item is clicked.

Like :

```
YourListview.ItemClicked+=(e,z)=>{ yourSingleFlyout.ShowAt(ElementClicked)};
```

Alternatively, like the other guy suggested, you can use a Multiview system, although i personally believe this kinda of UI design is as dead as windows phones.

Also, just for informative causes, Microsoft recently extended the **Placement** Enum for the Flyout entity on the latest api update, but i dont think there is something that might help you there.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Actually I don't really need a full-screen flyover, I just need the ability for it to be much wider and textboxes, font etc. to be much bigger. How would I increase the width responsively relative to the screen width?

Comment: this is a really tricky question, windows automatically scales the ui depending the screen and the device, so......